# Azure Logic Apps/Data Factory, getting files using FTPS

Tags: azure, ssl, ftp, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to get a file from a ftp server trough ftps.
This post is updated with more test results and knowledge from replies and my own research.
The ftp server support ftps Implicit SSL/TLS mode on port 990 and Exlicit mode on port 21.
I have tried to get the file from Logic apps and Data factory, both unsuccessful.

Testing Implicit mode.
Port 990, Enable SSL, Binary transport true/false tried both(Logic App), Server Certificate Validation disabled, yields this error:

Data factory error:

"Failed to connect to FTP server. ADF doesn't support SSL/TLS implicit encryption mode. Please make sure you are connecting by explicit encryption mode. The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation."

Logic apps error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 502,
    "source": "logic-apis-northeurope.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "c935a165-c725-4d26-824d-d1df3c82a65c",
    "message": "BadGateway",
    "innerError": {
      "status": 502,
      "message": "An FTP protocol violation was detected. This could be caused by an implicit TLS/SSL configuration of the FTP server that is not supported. Please try explicit TLS/SSL.\r\nclientRequestId: c935a165-c725-4d26-824d-d1df3c82a65c",
      "error": {
        "message": "An FTP protocol violation was detected. This could be caused by an implicit TLS/SSL configuration of the FTP server that is not supported. Please try explicit TLS/SSL."
      },
      "source": "ftp-ne.azconn-ne.p.azurewebsites.net"
    }
  }
}
```

As the response below indicate, either Data Factory nor Logig apps supports implicit mode.

Testing Explicit mode.
Port 21, Enable SSL, Binary transport true/false tried both(Logic App), Server Certificate Validation disabled, yields this error:

Data Factory error:

"Failed to connect to FTP server. Please make sure the provided server informantion is correct, and try again. The remote server returned an error: 150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/" . Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream"

Logic App error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 502,
    "source": "logic-apis-northeurope.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "61a1cc3e-74f3-40ac-a9f3-79a1409d81cc",
    "message": "The response is not in a JSON format.",
    "innerError": "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process."
  }
}
```

Test using FileZilla client.

Both implicit port(990) and explicit mode (port 21) works fine.
My original question where:
Is there any way to get the FTP connection in either Data factory or Logic Apps to work with SSL/TLS implicit mode?
As the response below states. Logic Apps and Data factory does not support Implicit mode.

A work around is to create a Function App, with c# code that gets the file trough implicit mode. And call the Function App from logic apps and/or data factory.

But why isn't explicit mode work?
Any tips?

Comment: Are you able to connect using an ftp client such as filezilla

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately neither Azure Data Factory nor Azure Logic Apps support Implicit TLS/SSL Configuration.  This is a known limitation.

**Azure Data Factory limitation**: The ADF FTP connector supports accessing FTP server with either no encryption or explicit SSL/TLS encryption; it doesn’t support implicit SSL/TLS encryption. (Ref: [Copy data from FTP server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/connector-ftp#linked-service-properties))

- Please consider to share your feedback/suggestion in ADF user voice forum about your requirement: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory

**Azure Logic Apps limitaiton**: The Azure Logic Apps FTP connector supports only explicit FTP over SSL (FTPS) and isn't compatible with implicit FTPS (Ref: [Azure Logic Apps FTP connector limiations](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp#limitations))

- There is already an existing feature request thread in Azure Logic Apps user voice forum related to this requirement, please feel free to up-vote and/or comment to increase the priority of the feature request: [Provide Implicit FTPS Capabilities with the FTP Connector](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/15201162-provide-implicit-ftps-capabilities-with-the-ftp-co)

Answer (score 1):

Implicit mode FTPS is deprecated, hence the lack of support in Azure services.

The error in explicit mode indicates that you actually connected and authenticated with the server. It tried to open a data channel to send a directory listing but the open request was 'closed'.

This error indicates you are using active mode when you probably should be using passive mode. In active mode the FTP server tries connect back to the client to create the data channel. There is a very strong chance that firewalls will prevent this. Using passive mode requires the client to connect to the server for the data channel. Better chance of firewalls allowing that connecting through.